# Half the modbus over tcp frame I send are invalid

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, modbus

I have made a c++ application and I needed to get some statistics from that application to an Modbus device over Tcp communication. The TCP communication is **made by socket** and i use send() to send my data.

And now half of the frames seems to be invalid : The first frame after the conection is always valid then the second is always false... and so on. And whenever i start a new connection the first frame is valid.

So i have checked on Wireshark and data-wise the Modbus Data are the same (except for the transaction identifier which is normal). The only thing which indicate an issue is the fact that Wireshark doesn't see the Frame as an Modbus frame if I "allow subdissector to reassemble tcp streams" in the Wireshark option i've got a new field: **"2 Reassembled TCP Segments (29 bytes): #79391(1), #79404(28)"** where #79391 is the frame number of the last correct frame and #79404 is the frame number of the current frame.

In order to avoid this i've tried to flush the tcp buffer by allowing TCP_NODELAY and i've got the exact same results. So if someone knows how to send the data in a way to avoid the Reassemble frame i'd gladly try any solution.

edit : I've solve my issue, the TCP wasn't wrong, of course. But it was doing something I do not thing possible adding the useless data of the buffer to the next frame. Long story short i was not sending the right amount of Data.

Comment: Why do you think the frames are invalid? TCP is allowed to break the stream up into packets any way it wants; that's how it works. So Ethereal/Wireshark needs to reassemble the TCP stream to be able to see the Modbus messages. That doesn't mean there's anything wrong with them.

Comment: My modbus master software could not understand one on two answers from its querrys. So I used several modbus master simulator to test my modbus slave and i have got the same result. One of them: QModMaster allows to see the modbus frame. And on the frame where Wireshark shows  the 2 reassembled fragment thing the simulator says: error->slave threw exception whereas the modbus part on the TCP frame are correct and is the expect answer

Answer (score 2):

I've solve my issue, the TCP wasn't wrong, of course. But it was doing something I do not thing possible adding the useless data of the buffer to the next frame. Long story short i was not sending the right amount of Data. –  Julien Amar